# How does the spring framework map properties to a Java Object?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to do something very similar to what spring `@ConfigurationProperties` does to map properties to a Java POJO, but at runtime. I am hoping to be able to reuse the spring framework code that does this for spring properties.

I looked through a bunch of spring's code but I am having trouble isolating the code that does this specific functionality. I can write my own algorithm to do this, but it feels like a waste since I know this is existing functionality in the spring framework and I have spring dependencies in my project already.

Comment: Why do you need to reuse the spring code? You better describe how you get the properties then we can help you find out a way to load them to Java entity.

Comment: I am playing with Spring-Shell to write a CLI and I want to load some configuration at runtime. This data could be entered by the user into the CLI a little bit at a time, but it feels like it would be more efficient to allow to load them from a property file. I'm thinking that maybe using YAML or JSON could make it easier since I can then use one of the many libraries to convert that to a POJO. Spring-Boot property management supports multiple formats as well as built-in validation so I figured reusing this would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I found the following class: `ConfigurationPropertiesBinder`, which binds properties from various `PropertySources` to a `Bindable` object. I was able to extract enough information from this bean to create my own version to do the conversion I was looking for.